# Liquibase tag command tags too much

Tags: mysql, database, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase for development. My DB is MySQL 5.5.42. Here is my sample changelog file:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1.0.0
      author: madhead
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: "changesets/001-create_tables.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            path: "changesets/-001-drop_tables.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
  - changeSet:
      id: 1.0.0-tag
      author: madhead
      changes:
        - tagDatabase:
            tag: 1.0.0
  - changeSet:
      id: 1.1.0
      author: madhead
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: "changesets/002-create_triggers.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
            endDelimiter: ";;"
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            path: "changesets/-002-drop_triggers.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
  - changeSet:
      id: 1.1.0-tag
      author: madhead
      changes:
        - tagDatabase:
            tag: 1.1.0
```

As you see, after every changeset I tag a database (is it ok at all?) I expect that `1.0.0-tag` and `1.1.0-tag` changesets get tagged accordingly after running `liquibase update` from scratch. But what I've get is all changesets tagged with latest tag:

[image: OMG, everything is tagged with latest tag!]

If I use `updateCount 1` four subsequent times everything is ok:

[image: What I want to see]

I think the problem can be `DATEEXECUTED` which is the same for all changesets. Is it a correct behaviour? How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your diagnosis that it is because all four changelog rows in the first example have the exact same date and time. Looking at [the documentation for the tagDatabase change](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/tag_database.html), it shows that the SQL generated is

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET TAG = 'version_1.3' WHERE DATEEXECUTED = (SELECT MAX(DATEEXECUTED) FROM (SELECT DATEEXECUTED FROM DATABASECHANGELOG) AS X);
```

I think the only workaround for you would be to use some method to ensure that the updates for different tags were run at slightly different times. Using the `updateCount 1` you mentioned is one way, but you could also use labels or contexts.

Comment: I've created a [defect for this](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2321) and they seem to [resolve it soon](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/392)